# Run Recipe on existing RSS entries

Tags: rss, if-this-then-that

I've created a recipe to backup content published to an RSS feed, but it only runs on new items. I am hoping there is a way to get it to run on all the historical items to, so that I don't have to do them all by hand.

Is this even possible with IFFT?

Comment: Check your RSS feed (paste it in the address bar of a browser) - it could be that it only aggregates the latest *n* items. If so, try to find a feed URL that contains all the items, or has a modifier parameter.

Comment: No, the feed contains all the entries I want to back up. Adding new items causes IFFT to pick them up, but it is ignoring the existing entries. This makes sense, because the IFFT recipe runs every 15 minutes, and it wouldn't want to get all the entries every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed IFTTT support about this and here's what they said:

> Really cool idea! This isn’t currently possible, but we’ll keep it in
>   mind. Thanks for sharing your feedback.
>
> Your Recipe will check your feed every ≈15 minutes for new
>   information. I hope that clears things up. If you have any further
>   questions, please let me know.

I know that email-to-RSS services like MailChimp and Aweber often look at the published date on the RSS item and only retrieve it if the date is within the last 24 hours. If possible, you might want to try modifying the date on your RSS feed items to something within the last 24 hours and see if IFTTT picks up more items. (You might be able to use [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) to modify the date on-the-fly and give IFTTT the Yahoo! Pipes feed.)

Otherwise, creating a PHP script that does what you need is probably the next best option.

Comment: I've never used yahoo pipes. If you could give some detail about using it to modify the date I will accept this answer.

Comment: @Tyrsius Here's a Yahoo! Pipes example for changing the PubDate on an RSS feed to tomorrow (you can change 'tomorrow' to any date you like): http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=058c093f0f878058c5613c96a1addd85